# Needed path variables for different conda virtual environments

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda

I've had troubles in setting up a `conda` virtual environment specifically intended to collect Deep Learning packages.
I read loads of tutorials, I also uninstalled and reinstalled Anaconda some times to make sure everything during the installation had been set properly.

I finally ended up with a virtual environment, say `DLenv`, in which `jupyter notebook` could not be launched (it simply did not run whatsoever. Browser used to open, but the `jupyter` home page did not load at all). After some researches I found out a possible solution in uninstalling `pyzmq`, installing it again and then installing again `jupyter`.

After launching the command

`(DLenv) C:/Users/.../folder > jupyter notebook`

the following message showed up:

`Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\Matteo\Anaconda3\envs\DLenv\python.exe C:\Users\Matteo\Anaconda3\envs\DLenv\Scripts\jupyter-script.py notebook'`

I somewhat felt the suspect that it was in some way due to the fact that the `DLenv` environment had few to do with the Anaconda installation step, when the user is asked whether include Anaconda in path variables or not. So I added both the paths of the object referred to in the above error to environment variables in my system but that still did not work. Finally I had the idea of **copying** the `python.exe` file referred to in the first part of the error in the second location mentioned, that is, in the directory dedicated to the new virtual environment.

Now it seems to work, in that from the `DLenv` `jupyter notebook` is lanched, kernel does not have connection issues.

**My question then is**: why on earth the `python.exe` object was required to be in the virtual environment folder and why it has not been moved there automatically during environment creation stage?

Shall I do the same *iter* every time a new environment is created?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to interface with Jupyter and Conda envs is to only install the `jupyter` package in a single env, which if you are using Anaconda already is **base**. You also need to install `nb_conda_kernels` in that env. Then, for every other env that you want to use as a kernel you install `ipykernel`. Launch `jupyter notebook` from the env that has it (**base**), and the other envs will be available as kernels.

There should be no manual manipulation of your `PATH` environment variable since Conda v4.4. Conda has its own internal tooling for managing this, and messing with it can lead to unexpected behavior.